# Waiting for a transaction to complete to execute in Node.js/Solidity

Tags: node.js, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I have been looking for a way to execute a set of commands after the completion of a transaction I sent.

In short, I have been testing small Node.js scripts with Web3.js to post thermometer readings to a smart contract and after the transaction is mined to get back the last 5 values posted.

I haven't found a specific Web3 method to do so, so I coded a *.on* method in Node.js. I am now looking for more optimised ways of doing it and together to query if there is a way of doing it using any of the Web3 methods.

PS - I suppressed the smart contract and parts of the Node script to save space on the post.

Cheers,

```
// Transaction
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1, (err, txCount) => {

  const txObject = {
    nonce:    web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(100000),
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('1', 'gwei')),
    to: contractAddress,
    data: contract.methods.postTemperature((Date.now() / 1000 | 0), temp).encodeABI()
  }

  const tx = new Tx(txObject)
  tx.sign(privateKey1)

  const serializedTx = tx.serialize()
  const raw = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')

  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, (err, txHash) => {
      txH = txHash;
    console.log('err:', err, 'txHash:', txHash)
  }).on('receipt', receipt => 
        contract.methods.seeTemperatures().call((err, result) => {
            const tempDisplay = 'The last five temperature submissions were: \n' + 
                (result[1].slice(-10))[8].toString() + 'ºC at ' + timeConverter((result[1].slice(-10))[9]).toString() + '\n' +
                (result[1].slice(-10))[6].toString() + 'ºC at ' + timeConverter((result[1].slice(-10))[7]).toString() + '\n' +
                (result[1].slice(-10))[4].toString() + 'ºC at ' + timeConverter((result[1].slice(-10))[5]).toString() + '\n' +
                (result[1].slice(-10))[2].toString() + 'ºC at ' + timeConverter((result[1].slice(-10))[3]).toString() + '\n' +
                (result[1].slice(-10))[0].toString() + 'ºC at ' + timeConverter((result[1].slice(-10))[1]).toString();
            console.log(tempDisplay)
        contract.methods.seeBill().call((err, result) => {console.log('Your current bill is at ' + result + ' (currency)')})
        })
    )
})
```

Comment: Create event in your contract and watch it. https://medium.com/@theMadKing/watching-solidity-events-the-right-way-d3d0a30bdc4d